# Building resizable jQuery Mobile carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying over many days to find a solution to small problem:

I seen many  **carousel images sliders** with navigation buttons, so you initialize dynamically number of images and build slider so you can navigate with NEXT and PREV buttons,but the all not resizable.
for example: http://www.bxslider.com/examples/display-move-multiple-slides-once-example-one

My problem is that I want to use `jQuery Mobile` and display it over `mobile`,where resolution is changing with every phone. The best wat to test whether it fit or not is to resize the browser window and check if the slider steal showen. In that example above its not resizable.

How can I build a similar thing with 3 images,1 in middle and 2 in conners with text under them and  with navigation buttons to scroll images by 1 image and the important thins so it be resizable.

Found similar example for phone: http://m.husqvarnacp.com/us/ but its not readable.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to scale your pages based on browser window resize, then you should have a look at this technique.
[How to implement a web page that scales when the browser window is resized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90595/how-to-implement-a-web-page-that-scales-when-the-browser-window-is-resized)

If the problem is only that images are of different sizes then you can fix the height of images and let the width vary so the slider doesn't effect the layout of the page.
Also consider this gallery slider plugin, [Step Carousel plugin](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/stepcarousel.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this using flexslider: http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/

It's very easy to setup and as you can see in the demo ( http://flexslider.woothemes.com/ ), it's responsive.

It also works with touch events so it's great for mobile.

Comment: Thanks,I looked at that example : [link] (http://flexslider.woothemes.com/basic-carousel.html) its something similar to what i'm looking for but if you resize it from start position of 3.5 images in a full size, it ends with 2 images. Also the scrolling there is not one by one.