# Picture thumbnail shown in Google image search output is <div> not <table>, why?

Tags: css, html, google-search

I have been learning HTML+CSS using codecademy.com

It was told in beginning, how to arrange images in grid/tables manner. It is done by using `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` tags.

You have to put `<a>` and `<img src ="">` in `<td>` tags.

But I noticed today images.google.com (search quinoa) doesn't show picture in tables.

There is `<div>` for every thumbnail. Why?

1. Does it make everything appear faster, i.e. `div`s are faster than `td`s?
2. No one uses tables anymore now a days. It is hard to read, manage HTML code?
3. There other coding strategy?

Comment: It is done using `<table>`? But I don't see any `<table>` tag in view source.

Comment: You should go with div rather than table(td/tr) because it will affect a lot areas.you can't make responsive site after coded in table easily..you can't add new rows, cols with easy while having thought of responsive. in iphone/android it will look like worst..but people are using table in these case where they can easily handle the design and where they don't need much modification..all it depends on user and his requirements but i will say go with div..best one

Comment: Using tables for *general* layout is considered old practice but for **tabular data** it's considered optimal. Using tables to layout a gallery or product list is perhaps a subjective case...I could go either way on it. That said, this question is, IMO, off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It basically comes down to preference. It is considered outdated to use `table` for data layouts. Use `table` for just that - actual tables. For the layout and such tasks, consider switching to `div` tags from now on. It has a lot of advantages, and is a topic much widely covered over the internet.

1. [Web Development Case Study: Upgrading Tables to Divs](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/web-development-case-study-upgrading-tables-to-divs.html)
2. [Why use Div tags instead of tables?](http://www.allmyit.com.au/why-use-div-tags-instead-of-tables)
3. [`<div>` element instead of `<table>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819237/div-element-instead-of-table)