# Is there a simple 3-column, pure CSS layout?

Tags: html, css

One that doesn't require the following:

1. Reliance on images (i.e. "faux columns")
2. Some kind of weirdness or "hack" put in specifically for IE
3. Requires IE to run in quirks mode
4. Doesn't have strangeness like one of the three DIVs overlapping the others (i.e. "holy grail")
5. Margins set to high negative numbers placing them well off the viewscreen (again "holy grail" layout)

I can't find a 3-column layout in CSS that doesn't rely on one of the above.  And relying on one of the above seems to negate a lot of the advantage of using CSS over tables.  I don't want to have to whip out Photoshop and resize an image every time I want to change the width of my left column.  And I don't want to have to pull out the calculator to figure out how many pixels off the side of the screen my DIV has to be.

I should mention that I'm looking for an equal-height layout.

Anyone?

EDIT: I'm looking for a width of 100%, with the center column being liquid.

EDIT: I'm also hoping to specify the width of the left and right columns in pixels.

EDIT: Backgrounds can be transparent, but I would like a dividing line between the columns which runs all the way up and down.

Comment: Errare humanum est - I don't think you'll be able to get away without hacks. Especially because of equal heights. Depends of course on the version of CSS you wish to be your base.

Comment: You need to specify your requirements for borders and background colours/images. 3 columns with transparent backgrounds and no borders is easy to do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no such thing as "simple" when you talk about CSS.

But there is a simple solution that is cross browser, degrades gracefully and is fully HTML and CSS compliant: use a table with three columns.

Reasoning: DIVs are not meant to have the same dynamic height. Therefore, CSS has no support for this. If you need a block element which makes sure that its children have the same height, then that's what tables are for.

[EDIT] Sorry to offend all you CSS fanatics out there but, frankly, when something is not designed to do something and you abuse it, and it doesn't work, please stop complaining, ok? A DIV is not a TABLE and can't be used as one without relying on hacks.

[EDIT2] As was said already in [various places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/82391/should-tables-be-avoided-in-html-at-any-cost), the reason not to use tables for layout was that, in early times, tables were the *only* design element and that lead to HTML which had dozens of nested tables. That's bad. But that doesn't mean you **must not** use a single table to put everything in place and then rely on CSS to make the stuff inside look right.

A brain is like a parachute: It's nice to have but only useful when it's open.

Comment: Tables were designed for expressing relationships between bits of data (with each item in a row having something in common and each item in a column having something in common). Having all the cells in a row share a height is a consequence, not a cause.

Comment: Well, you have a goal and you have two tools. One is frowned upon and the other doesn't fit the bill at all ... which one do you use?

Comment: +1 there is no shame using a table for layout as long as it stays simple.

Comment: This would all not a problem if all browsers would support display: table-cell etc -- once again it's Internet Explorer spoiling it for everyone.

Comment: I don´t think there is just one solution that suits all. I have not resorted to tables in a very long time for a 3-column layout, including complex layouts, but I guess I might if it seems the best solution. Analysing the graphic design dictates the way to go, but I can´t help thinking in blocks instead of cells and tables, things have changed.

Comment: @jeroen: That's what I say: Use your brain. I see you didn't post an answer for this question. Why is that? Can it be done with CSS without hacks? I have my doubts.

Comment: ie 8 has some serious bug setting max width on image tags inside a table which forces you to go for the hacky div solution

Answer (score 6):

You might be able adapt:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

Comment: That one does look promising, but I guess I should have mentioned I am looking for one with pixel-width columns, not percentage width.  That same website contains a template for pixel widths (the "holy grail" one I mentioned above) but it's a very convoluted stylesheet, which I would have to say is less desirable than using tables for layout.

That one would be very good though for someone who needs percentage-width columns, though.

Comment: Here is a pixel width version:

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/holy-grail-no-quirks-mode.htm

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Robert. Due to browsers interpreting CSS rules and rendering the final page differently I doubt you'll find a perfect solution without being more flexible in your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can achive this by using jS.

If you were to create 3 Divs one float left one flot right and the middle as margin left & right with a width to centre it.

Then with a bit of JS each div having their own ID you could calcultate their height set the 2 lowers ones to the highest value.

Pretty simple with Jquery.

Comment: True, it's easy with javascript... but he asked for a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

http://960.gs/

This one can be used for a 3-column layout (and for various other layouts). Personally, I don't think it's a great idea to use divs for everything, but it's simple and well .. it works.

edit: For a 100% width layout http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/ may help, but I'm not sure if this kind of layout still qualifies as "simple".

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned that I'm looking for a 100% width (with the center column being liquid).

Comment: Yeah, the one from a list apart looks a little complex.  One of those where it's not really clear which is less desirable, using a stylesheet that complicated, or using a table even though tables aren't intended for layout.

Answer (score 0):

[YAML](http://www.yaml.de)

> "Yet Another Multicolumn Layout"
>   (YAML) is an (X)HTML/CSS framework for
>   creating modern and flexible floated
>   layouts. The structure is extremely
>   versatile in its programming and
>   absolutely accessible for end users.

It contains some IE bug fixes, but you can remove them.

Answer (score -2):

divide page into three columns, same height?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#col_wrapper{
    height: 400px;
}

.col{
    width: 33%;
    float:left;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="col_wrapper">
    <div class="col">
        one
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        two
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        three
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

no quirks and pretty plain.

Comment: Should have mentioned that fixed-height wouldn't work.  One page might have 5 paragraphs of text in the middle column, another might have 25.