# Javascript / jQuery - Parse returned 'data' as HTML for further selecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

a webservice returns some data to me. The data is actually just raw HTML (so no XML header, or  tags around it, but just a piece of html).

```
<div class="Workorders">
    <div id="woo_9142" class="Workorder">
        <span class="Workorder">S1005</span>
        <span class="Pn">30-2</span>
        <span class="Description">Cooling Fan</span>
        <span class="Shortages">3616-1 (SV)</span>
        <span class="Company">xxx</span>
    </div>
    <div id="woo_9143" class="Workorder">
        <span class="Workorder">S1006</span>
        <span class="Pn">30-2</span>
        <span class="Description">Cooling Fan</span>
        <span class="Shortages">3616-1 (SV)</span>
        <span class="Company">xxx</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**If this were XML like so:**

```
<workorders>
    <workorder id="woo_9142">
        <partnumber>30-2</partnumber>
    </workorder>
</workorders>
```

**I could go like this in jQuery:**

```
$('/workorders/workorder', data).each(function() {
    //This would give every partnumber $('partnumber', this).text();
});
```

**How can I parse the returned HTML (like described at the beginning)?**

```
myNamespace.onSuccess = function(request) {
    //request contains the raw html string returned from the server

    //How can I make this possible:
    $(request).find('div.Workorders div.Workorder').each(function() {
       //Do something with the Workorder DIV in 'this'
    });
}
```

Comment: You should use a <table> for this kind of data though.

Comment: Do i? ;) Every DIV has different 'viewtypes' which are built based on CSS...

Comment: You should probably read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251/tables-instead-of-divs

It wouldn't be too hard to change only your CSS selector I think.

Comment: Lol, -read- my comment. I really need divs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like

```
myNamespace.onSuccess = function(request) {    
    $(request.responseText).filter('div.Workorder').each(function() {
       $('span.Pn', $(this)).text();
    });
}
```

Comment: I found another solution which is similar to the xml parsing: $('div.Workorder', request).each(function() {}); which does the trick in the old fasion jQuery way... Anyway this is probably closest solution... :)

Comment: @ropstah - what you have looks cleaner. That's what I get for not writing any jQuery for a couple of weeks... :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding the html to the dom, hiding it and then process it:

```
myNamespace.onSuccess = function(request) {
    var hidden = document.createElement ( 'div' );
    hidden.id = 'hiddenel';
    $("body").append ( hidden );
    $("#hiddenel").css ( 'visibility', 'hidden' );
    $("#hiddenel").html ( resp );
    $("#hiddenel").find ( 'div.Workorders div.Workorder').each(function() {
    .....
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify explicitly the return type you are expecting: http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

Comment: I'm not using jQuery for the AJAX request. I'm working with .NET MVC which has it's AJAX functions built in. In the background it does use jQuery, but I don't have control...