# How to switch from table to div for FORM layout?

Tags: html, css, forms, html-table

I'm noticing most folks are talking about using DIVs and CSS for
label, textbox pairs.  How would one convert a table such as:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><some Label1> </td>
      <td><some TextBox1> </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td><some Label2> </td>
      <td><some TextBox2> </td>
   </tr>
   ...
</table>
```

From using a table into say a div with CSS, a sample would be helpful!  Currently I was using a table for such a thing, imagine say a site that just displays some user information.  How would I display the pairs (the label, the text box) using DIVs rather than table format?

Assume the labels / textbox's are ASP.net labels and textboxes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider this article at Woork titled [Clean and Pure CSS Form Design](http://woork.blogspot.com/2008/06/clean-and-pure-css-form-design.html)

I've implemented this style, including the `fieldset` and tweaked all the styles appropriately for the look/feel that was required.

Consider using `<label runat="server">` to inherit the style of the label via CSS instead of `asp:label`. Alternatively you could put your `asp:label` within `label` tags. Since `asp:label` emits `<span>`, that would simply result in a set of `<label><span></span></label>`.

[image]

Comment: @pcampbell, nice what I am most interested in is the "Add your name", "Add valid address" etc right below each bold label.  Can you share the CSS for this form and the HTML?

Comment: if you are going to use <label> tags in your markup, consider using an <asp:literal> instead of <asp:label>.  The resulting markup will have no <span> tags :)

Comment: Just FYI, in the 3 or something years since this answer, <asp:labels> don't render <span>s, as long as they have an "
AssociatedControlID" attribute set.

Comment: @p.campbell, just got time to add the example this morning.

Comment: great answer, the link "Clean and Pure CSS Form Design" is not available, but found this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/MVLZd/) to the implementation

Answer (score 8):

Consider this article titled [Tableless forms using CSS](http://www.cssdrive.com/index.php/examples/exampleitem/tableless_forms/) from CssDrive.

A little bit of style really helps. I've been refactoring/replacing all my table'd forms with the pattern found in the article above.

With the following code:

- asp:textbox works perfectly, needs no modification for all kinds of textboxes
- asp:button works perfectly, needs no modification
- asp:checkbox would likely need modification, perhaps wrapped in another div with a special style

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1YBW.png]

Here's the basic example presented:

**The CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">

label{
float: left;
width: 120px;
font-weight: bold;
}

input, textarea{
width: 180px;
margin-bottom: 5px;
}

textarea{
width: 250px;
height: 150px;
}

.boxes{
width: 1em;
}

#submitbutton{
margin-left: 120px;
margin-top: 5px;
width: 90px;
}

br{
clear: left;
}

</style>
```

**The HTML:**

```
<form>

<label for="user">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="user" value="" /><br />

<label for="emailaddress">Email Address:</label>
<input type="text" name="emailaddress" value="" /><br />

<label for="comments">Comments:</label>
<textarea name="comments"></textarea><br />

<label for="terms">Agree to Terms?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="terms" class="boxes" /><br />

<input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Extract from my code:

```
<div>
    <label for="Password"> Password:</label>
    <input id="Password" type="password" name="Password"/>
    <label for="ConfirmationPassword"> Confirmation: </label>
    <input id="ConfirmationPassword" type="password" name="ConfirmationPassword"/>
<div class="clear"/>
</div>
<div>
    <label for="FirstName"> Prénom:</label>
    <input id="FirstName" type="text" value="" name="FirstName"/>
    <label for="LastName"> Nom:</label>
    <input id="LastName" type="text" value="" name="LastName"/>
    <div class="clear"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

with the following css:

```
label {
    float:left;
    margin-right:0.5em;
    margin-top:10px;
    padding-left:5px;
    text-align:justify;
    width:200px;
}

input[type="text"], textarea, input[type="password"], input[type="checkbox"], select {
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used basically the same idea for creating a tableless form layout. But, I use an unordered list to hold my labels and inputs. For example:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <ul class="formFields">
            <li>
                <label for="user">
                    Name</label><input type="text" name="user" value="" /></li>
            <li>
                <label for="emailaddress">
                    Email Address:</label><input type="text" name="emailaddress" value="" /></li>
            <li>
                <label for="comments">
                    Comments:</label><textarea name="comments"></textarea></li>
            <li>
                <label for="terms">
                    Agree to Terms?</label><input type="checkbox" name="terms" class="boxes" /></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" /></p>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The CSS styles can be just the same as what pcampbell has used in his example. The only difference for mine would be the addition of a style for the UL such as:

```
ul {list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@p.cambell answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760856/3806089) and [the implementation with css](http://jsfiddle.net/MVLZd/), I wrote this code in asp.net for a login popup screen:

**css**

```
.flotante-login {
    border:solid 2px #b7ddf2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px;
    background:#ebf4fb;
}
.loginBox {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#login{
}
#login h1 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
#login p{
       font-size:11px;
       color:#666666;
       margin-bottom:20px;
       border-bottom:solid 1px #b7ddf2;
       padding-bottom:10px;
   }
   #login label{
       display:block;
       font-weight:bold;
       text-align:right;
       width:140px;
       float:left;
   }
   #login .small{
       color:#666666;
 display:block;
       font-size:11px;
       font-weight:normal;
       text-align:right;
       width:140px;
   }
   #login input{
       float:left;
       font-size:12px;
       padding:4px 2px;
       border:solid 1px #aacfe4;
       width:200px;
       margin:2px 0 20px 10px;
   }
   #login a{
       clear:both;
       width:125px;
       padding: 10px;
       background-color: #E2B66B;
       color:#FFFFFF;
       text-align:center;
       text-decoration: none !important;
       line-height:30px;
       font-weight:bold;
       color: #FFF !important;
       border-radius: 5px;
   }
```

**aspx page**:

```
<div id="popupLogin" class="flotante-login" style="display:none;">
    <asp:Panel ID="panelLogin" runat="server" DefaultButton="lbLogin">
        <div id="login" class="loginBox">
            <h1>Acceso</h1>
            <label>
                Usuario:
                <span class="small">Ingresa tu email</span>
            </label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUsuario" runat="server" MaxLength="250"></asp:TextBox>
            <label>
                Contraseña:
                <span class="small">Ingresa tu contraseña</span>
            </label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" MaxLength="8" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lbLogin" Text="Ingresa" runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

The **result** is:
[image: Login popup screen]

Comment: does your login screen behaves like a modal window?

Comment: @DanielV yes it is a popup modal window, I use [jquery blockui](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) if you are wondering