# Non-css styling considerations for html, javascript and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, layout

Im trying to get a sense for proper web development techniques , and im wondering if there are any habits i should be developing outside of css usage in terms of structure and layout.

What I've gotten so far is a sense that strategic and logical use of divs can help to give needed control when working with javascript and css.

But are there any other basic things i should consider that may not be aware of?

For example, I know people used to control layout with tables, but is that still a thing? Or is it now bad practice?

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your table question- People generally choose divs over tables, BUT some things cannot be done well without tables. They still have their place. Divs and Tables inset within each other are often used for datagrid styled layouts for example. Often replacing tables with divs creates a nasty (oversized) amount of css code. If you can use divs cleanly, that is perfect. If it overbloats your code, then use the simpler cleaner old faithful table code - or combine them where it makes for better results.

More info on that here: [Tables instead of DIVs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30251/tables-instead-of-divs) (Joel Coehoorn's detailed answer: "The whole "Tables vs Divs" thing just barely misses the mark. It's not "table" or "div". It's about using semantic html.")

Regarding the topic of non-CSS since your question also refers to layout design formatting:

There are some things you cannot do well also without pure CSS, that in and of itself allows modern formats to work on multiple devices. This will reach more customers.

For newer layout types for sections of pages needing icons or photos, look into the use of inline-block styled lists. CSS does wonders with them. It is a nice third alternative.

For cross-device development, you should check out responsive and fluid formatting options. A good place to start is to look at http://html5boilerplate.com/ and also http://www.initializr.com/ (boilerplate and bootstrap).

If you haven't worked with them before, look into media queries for browser sizing and device orientation displays (landscape or portrait) - part of the fundamentals in responsive web development. You can then use your regular html within the constraints you set with these.

Answer (score 1):

Try to think of your pages/documents in terms of structure rather than appearance.  For example, a book is made up of a title page, table of contents and chapters.  Similarly, the contents of a web page can usually be broken down into logical blocks, which are *then* styled as required.  Don't forget that web pages may be read by screen readers - your want to structure your page so the spoken output makes sense.

There has been a discussion of tables vs CSS at [Why not use tables for layout in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html).  You may also want to check out CSS Zen Garden, mentioned in that thread.  Beyond this, I strongly recommend validating any HTML and CSS you write.  Check out http://validator.w3.org/ for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Divs are span are a better options for laying out a page. Tables should be used if tabular data is to be displayed.

Other than that you should mostly consider re-factoring redundant code regularly and resolve paths to directories in config files. This will help you to manage your project better. Redundant code can become a huge problem, since making changes requires changing code at several places. Make sure that you re-factor code that is being used more than once or twice  into functions and call them instead.

Try diving into CSS frameworks such as bootstrap or foundation since a big community contributes there and are usually built with best practices in mind. You will be surprised to see the problems you run into have already been encountered by many others and they have found an efficient way around it too. There are frameworks and libraries for JS too. Feel free to explore.